PDAL one liner : using same filter twice
I just want a confirmation that it is not possible to do the following PDAL pipeline as a one line command :
[
    "in.ply",
    {
        "type" : "filters.ferry",
        "dimensions" : "class=>Classification"
    },
    {
        "type" : "filters.neighborclassifier",
        "domain" : "Classification[0:0]",
        "k" : 10
    },
    {
        "type" : "filters.ferry",
        "dimensions" : "Classification=>class"
    },
    { 
        "type" : "writers.ply",
        "filename":"out.ply",
        "precision":"6",
        "dims":"x,y,z,intensity,class"
    }
]

i tried :
pdal translate in.ply out.ply \
ferry neighborclassifier ferry \
--filters.ferry.dimensions="class=>Classification" \
--filters.neighborclassifier.domain="Classification[0:0]" \
--filters.neighborclassifier.k="10" \
--filters.ferry.dimensions="Classification=>class" \
--writers.ply.precision="6" \
--writers.ply.dims="x,y,z,intensity,class"

But seems like it doesn't work.
I can make it work if i remove the last ferry :
pdal translate in.ply out.ply \
ferry neighborclassifier \
--filters.ferry.dimensions="class=>Classification" \
--filters.neighborclassifier.domain="Classification[0:0]" \
--filters.neighborclassifier.k="10" \
--writers.ply.precision="6" \
--writers.ply.dims="x,y,z,intensity,Classification"

But then I end up with the class field with a different naming notation (for context i can not do directly filters.neighborclassifier.domain="class[0:0]" because the filter neighborclassifier can ONLY take as input a field named "Classification").
Can someone confirm that i can not use twice the same filter twice in a single command line ? I use PDAL 2.7.1

You can pass the JSON as a string to pdal translate to make a one line command.
pdal translate in.ply out.ply --json \
 '[
    {    
       "type" :"filters.ferry",    
       "dimensions" :"class=>Classification"    
    },    
    {    
       "type" :"filters.neighborclassifier",    
       "domain" :"Classification[0:0]",    
       "k" : 10    
    },    
    {    
       "type" :"filters.ferry",    
       "dimensions" :"Classification=>class"    
    },    
    {     
       "type" :"writers.ply",    
       "precision":"6",    
       "dims":"x,y,z,intensity,class"    
    }    
]'


For you last comment, yes i am sure about my assertion. filters.neighborclassifier can only work on Classifiation dimension, and class is not recognized as Classification. I asked on the pdal github (link), they actually added the name class as well as cls as a synonym of Classification. It will be released in 2.9.0.

with futher testing : pdal translate in.ply out.ply ferry --filters.ferry.dimensions="class=>Classification" neighborclassifier --filters.neighborclassifier.domain="Classification[0:0]" --filters.neighborclassifier.k="10" --writers.ply.precision="6" works (but then you have not done the last ferry)

then if you apply the last ferry :  pdal translate in.ply out_2.ply ferry --filters.ferry.dimensions="class=>Classification" neighborclassifier --filters.neighborclassifier.domain="Classification[0:0]" --filters.neighborclassifier.k="10" ferry --filters.ferry.dimensions="Classification=>class" --writers.ply.precision="6" you do no longer have the Classification being correct. I dont understand...

I also see that pdal info --summary small_tile.ply does not report a "class" dimension.  It shows "classification" and pdal translate small_tile.ply out.ply neighborclassifier --filters.neighborclassifier.domain="classification[0:0]" --filters.neighborclassifier.k="10" --writers.ply.precision="6" works for me.

yeah , i am sorry, i oubviously sent the wrong one (new small_tile.ply. I re-checked everything : i can do ferry+neighbour+ferry as a pipeline but not as command line. As command lines : If i do ferry+neighbour it works (neigbours filter applied). When i do f+n+f then even the Classification field do not have the result of the neighbour filter. (For info : i did these tests with your order of writting the command lines)

tests on 2.4.2 yield the same results
